# upload and save file using browse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, beego

html i have tried is

```html
<form action="upload">
  <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

and now i want this browsed file to be stored in some location with file name remaining same.
using beego as web framework along with simple html javascript

Comment: try to check uploadify, or http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp, http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: @Farhan,, i dont want to do it using php

Comment: you need to use server side scripting to move files from temp to required. What are you using for server side scripting?

Answer (score 2):

You can use getuikit upload component http://getuikit.com/docs/upload.html . It utilizes XMLHttpRequest Level 2. Of course you have to set target url with image proccessing script. In your case probably go language.

Comment: i agree but i need to know how to do it with go

Comment: I don't know a thing about go, but in beego docs there's a chapter saying about uploading files. http://beego.me/docs/mvc/controller/params.md#uploading-files. Try to place it inside apropriate controller.